# x86-64 accessing element of array

Tags: assembly, x86-64, att, addressing-mode

Hi I am a beginner in assembly language, is there a difference between `movl (%rdi,%r12), %r10d`  and `movl (%rdi,%r12,4), %r10d`? I tried both of them and they both seem to do the same job-- saving the element of %rdi at %r12 position to %r10d. Is the 4 in the 2nd example really necessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they are different.

Suppose for example that `%rdi = 0x12340000` and `%r12 = 8`.  Then `movl (%rdi,%r12), %r10d` adds `%r12` to `%rdi` to form an effective address, so you load a 32-bit dword from address `0x12340008`.  The `4` is the scale parameter of the SIB addressing mode; it causes `%r12` to be multiplied by 4 before adding to `%rdi`, so with `movl (%rdi,%r12,4), %r10d` you load a 32-bit dword from address `0x12340020` instead.

See the [GNU as manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002dMemory.html#i386_002dMemory):  "If no `scale` is specified, `scale` is taken to be 1."

If you try it with an array defined like

```
int32_t foo[] = {1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25};
```

and `%rdi` contains the address of `foo`, with `%r12 = 8` as above, then `movl (%rdi,%r12), %r10d` will load `%r10d` with the value `5`, but `movl (%rdi,%r12,4), %r10d` will load it with the value `17`.  In other words, it is a question of whether you are treating `%rdi` as a count of bytes, or a count of 32-bit ints.

If they appear to work the same in your test, then either your test is buggy, or the two different addresses happen by coincidence to contain the same value, or your `%r12` is zero, or your assembler is broken (unlikely).

Comment: thank you! I figured out the problem, I was using movb to test and thought movl will behave the same way...

Comment: @M.Chen: They are still different with `movb`.

Comment: Um doesn't movb move one byte of data? I think I will read the manual and try to understand the instructions, thank you for your help!

Comment: @M.Chen: It does move one byte of data.  But with the examples as above, `movb (%rdi, %r12), %r10b` would move the byte from address `0x12340008` while `movb (%rdi, %r12, 4), %r10b` would move the byte from address `0x12340020`.  The scale parameter acts the same regardless of the operand size.